# Transparent element on top of visible element

Tags: javascript, html, css

Is there a way to make a transparent element appear on top of a visible element? I want NAV2 that is transparent to be on top of the yellow square like NAV1 does despite being transparent.I need the nav to be transparent and the square that appears when you click on the button to go beneath it.

Thank you!

Here is the code:

```js
buttons = document.querySelectorAll('button');
elements = document.querySelectorAll('.element');


buttons.forEach((button, i) => {
button.addEventListener('click', function() {
  elements[i].classList.add('animate-element');
})
});

elements.forEach(element => element.addEventListener('animationend', function() {
   element.classList.remove('animate-element');
}))
```

```css
.nav1, .nav2 {
  position: relative;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 20vh;
  color: white;
}

.nav1 {
  background: red;
}

.nav2 {
  border: 2px solid black;
}

button {
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.button1 {
  margin-bottom: 120px;
}

.element1, .element2 {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
  height: 80px;
  background: yellow;
  bottom: -105%;
  right: 5%;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: -1;
}

.animate-element {
  animation: animate 1.2s ease forwards;
}

@keyframes animate {
  0% {
    transform: scale(0);
    opacity: 1;
  }
  
    35% {
    transform: scale(1);
    opacity: 1;
  }
  
  70% {
    transform: scale(1);
    opacity: 1;
  }
  
    100% {
    transform: scale(1) translateY(-140%);
    opacity: 1;
  } 
}
```

```html
<div class="nav1">
  <div class="element1 element"></div>
  NAV1
</div>
<button class="button1">Button1</button>

<div class="nav2">
   NAV2
  <div class="element2 element"></div>
</div>
<button class="button1">Button2</button>
```

Comment: Why not simply use zIndex?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events

Comment: I see, you want to hide a colorful div/container below a transparent div/container. I don't think this is possible without extensive javascript.

Comment: Yes, I want the colored div to be beneath the div that is transparent and have a border.

Answer (score 1):

Do you want to see the page Background? This is not possible. But you can use z-index: n; to move your transparent Element n layers above the others. You can't see this but it's above.

Comment: I want the yellow box to go beneath the transparent  element with the black border and when it is beneath it to not be visible.

Comment: But your transparent object is 0x0px big, so there is no border. Make it as big as your yellow box and add the color of the background.

Comment: No, it have a width of 100vw.Click Run code snippet and scroll, there is a second nav container.

Comment: Oh, I didn't see the scrollbar xD. If it's transparent, you can see trough it. Try to add background: #FFFFFF; to n2. Or am I stupid...

Comment: I want nav2 to be transparent  and to appear on top when the colored box is beneath it :D , I don't want it to have a background color but I don't know if it is possible.

Comment: But the yellow box is under the black frame. Would you like to see the yellow box not when it is under the frame but only when it is peeping out? With CSS this is not possible

Comment: Yes, that's what I wanted :(.

Comment: I'm sorry, but as I said, this is not possible I tink. The only option is with background.